# OOP - Applying attributes and methods of multiple classes to a single class

Tags: java, oop

I'm writing a piece of code for a small card game as a side project in java and have come across an issue I can't find an elagent solution to using OOP.

I have an abstract class `Card` and then two concrete classes `Creature` and `Machine`. What I want to do is have a card that is both a Creature and a Machine, but without creating a new `Machine_Creature` class as this means writing the same code that creature and machine already have.

I'm looking for a way to create this `Machine_Creature` class that enables it to obtain the funtionality of both `Machine` and `Creature` and prevent me from just copy and pasting the code from one place to another just to enable the functionality

Below is some example code of what my current structure looks like

```
public abstract class Card {
   //Card related methods and attributes
}

public class Machine extends Card {
   //Machine related methods and attributes
}

public class Creature extends Card {
   //Creature related methods and attributes
}

public class MachineCreature extends Card {
   //MachineCreature related methods and attributes
   //Problems arise here as we have to rewrite the code Creature and Machine 
   //already use
}
```

Comment: Java unfortunately (or fortunately) doesn't have multiple inheritance. You should look at composition instead: For instance, create a new class that has an instance of `Creature` and `Machine`. With the composition approach, you aren't duplicating any of the code.

Comment: Without any code, there's no way to guess the similarities and differences of and between those classes.

Comment: See my answer: if you want to think "A is a B", you need abstract classes. interfaces are about "A is able to do something".

Comment: Your only other option is to define `Card`, `Machine` and `Creature` as interfaces and have `MachineCreature` implement both Machine and Creature.

Comment: This is a common problem, one solution to which is to use the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Another way would be to use interfaces, rather than inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Java dont allow multiple inheritance. A solution to your problem is to use composition.

```
 Class MachineCreature {
    Machine machine;
    Creature creature;
    ...other sepecific methods and attributes
 }
```

Comment: The problem I forsee here is that I lose the ability to remain generic when talking about Cards as a whole. MachineCreature should extend Card so as to obtain generic Card functions, but also wants to have access to Machine and Creature functions. If I implement composition I have to write in less generic code that looks out for if a Card has class atrributes as well as if it is of the class type, where I want to just be able to look at the class and figure out what I'm looking at from there

Answer (score -1):

Introducing a new level in the hierarchy can solve problem,maintaning the "is a" relationship beetween the objects.I mean

```
class abstract Card{
    //methods
 }

class MachineCreature extends Card{
   //methods in common beetween Machine and Creature implemented
 }

class Machine extends MachineCreature{
   //specific methods for Machine class
   //optional overloading of parent class
}

class Creature extends MachineCreature{
   //specific methods for Creature class
   //optional overloading of parent class
}
```

Otherwise, I don't like very much this solution.
If I were you I would reconsider the solution involving composition given by Patricia.